# Windows 8 clock keeps stopping and needs to be reset

Tags: windows-7, bios, battery

I have a PC with Windows 8.

In the last 2 days I have set the clock (the one which appears at the right bottom corner of the desktop) twice, as it paused on a certain hour and (Maybe the hour before I shutdown the PC?).

What can cause that?

Could the BIOS battery be at fault?

Comment: What does "it stops working" mean? What *precisely* happens or doesn't happen?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and take some time... It doesn't make any sense as it currently stands... What is at the bottom of the screen? -1

Comment: If you suspect the BIOS battery, why haven't you changed it yet?

Comment: I did. 3 hours after I have sent the question. Just wanted to be sure if there is nothing else to replace.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/272868/how-can-a-cmos-battery-store-data/272872#272872

Comment: Make sure your clock is set to "automatically synchronize with time.windows.com" (or "time.nist.gov" or one of the other options).  (Click the clock, select "Change date and time settings", and click "Internet time" to check this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can only presume what you might have meant by "clock is stopped", that every time you boot-up after shutting it down completely, the clock perhaps resets (and perhaps resets to 1-Jan-1970). However, while you work on the PC, over time, the clock keeps ticking. You could always manually set the time, but powering-off, you lose the set time.

Highly likely that the CMOS battery for the onboard Real-Time Clock (RTC), managed by the PC BIOS is dead. So indeed, changing the CMOS battery should be attempted first to fix this.

You could also stop the PC boot-up, and enter the PC BIOS, check the time reported there. If it shows 1-Jan-1970 in BIOS, and you set the date/time to current, and shutdown/power-off and reboot, then re-enter BIOS and again find time as 1-Jan-1970, then it is almost certainly the CMOS battery.